# Linear regression with pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I tried to run linear regression on ForestFires dataset. 
Dataset is available on Kaggle and gist of my attempt is here: 
https://gist.github.com/Chandrak1907/747b1a6045bb64898d5f9140f4cf9a37

I am facing two problems:

1. Output from prediction is of shape 32x1 and target data shape is 32.

> input and target shapes do not match: input [32 x 1], target [32]¶

Using view I reshaped predictions tensor.

> y_pred = y_pred.view(inputs.shape[0])

Why there is a mismatch in shapes of predicted tensor and actual tensor?

2. SGD in pytorch never converges. I tried to compute MSE manually using

> print(torch.mean((y_pred - labels)**2))

This value does not match

> loss = criterion(y_pred,labels)

Can someone highlight where is the mistake in my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem 1

This is reference about MSELoss from Pytorch docs: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.MSELoss

```
Shape:
 - Input: (N,∗) where * means, any number of additional dimensions
 - Target: (N,∗), same shape as the input
```

So, you need to expand dims of labels: (32) -> (32,1), by using: `torch.unsqueeze(labels, 1)` or `labels.view(-1,1)`

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze

> torch.unsqueeze(input, dim, out=None) → Tensor
>
> Returns a new tensor with a dimension of size one inserted at the specified position.
>
> The returned tensor shares the same underlying data with this tensor.

#### Problem 2

After reviewing your code, I realized that you have added `size_average` param to MSELoss:

```
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(size_average=False)
```

> size_average (bool, optional) – Deprecated (see reduction). By default, the losses are averaged over each loss element in the batch. Note that for some losses, there multiple elements per sample. If the field size_average is set to False, the losses are instead summed for each minibatch. Ignored when reduce is False. Default: True

That's why 2 computed values not matched. This is sample code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

loss1 = nn.MSELoss()
loss2 = nn.MSELoss(size_average=False)
inputs = torch.randn(32, 1, requires_grad=True)
targets = torch.randn(32, 1)

output1 = loss1(inputs, targets)
output2 = loss2(inputs, targets)
output3 = torch.mean((inputs - targets) ** 2)

print(output1)  # tensor(1.0907)
print(output2)  # tensor(34.9021)
print(output3)  # tensor(1.0907)
```

Comment: Great. This resolved problem 1. However, loss computed using torch.mean((y_pred - labels)**2) are not matching loss = criterion(y_pred,labels). Can you pls let me know, how they are different?

Comment: @Chandra I've realized that your code's using `size_average` param. I've updated my answer for detail

Comment: Yes. Thank you.